# Warning message during building an R package: invalid uid value replaced by that for user 'nobody'

Tags: r

I was building an R package using `R CMD build ABC` and got this warning message:

```
* building ‘milonga_1.0.tar.gz’
Warning: invalid uid value replaced by that for user 'nobody'
```

I have no idea what it means. Would somebody have a brief explanation?

Comment: Did you happen to do a search on this? Seems like the answer is already out there... https://www.google.com/search?q=Warning%3A+invalid+uid+value+replaced+by+that+for+user+%27nobody%27&oq=Warning%3A+invalid+uid+value+replaced+by+that+for+user+%27nobody%27&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.415j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: As usual, this page is now the top hit on Google and the foregoing comment looks silly

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I get this all the time. **tl;dr** you can ignore it, it has to with the problem that `tar` files can't portably allow user IDs greater than 32767, but user IDs on some systems are greater than this.

Searching the code on [Winston Chang's Github mirror of the R source tree](https://github.com/wch/r-source/) finds this code in [src/library/utils/R/tar.R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed415a8431b32e079100f50a846e4769aeb54d5a/src/library/utils/R/tar.R):

```
 uid <- info$uid
 ## uids are supposed to be less than 'nobody' (32767)
 ## but it seems there are broken ones around: PR#15436
 if(!is.null(uid) && !is.na(uid)) {
      if(uid < 0L || uid > 32767L) {invalid_uid <- TRUE; uid <- 32767L}
      header[109:115] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%07o", uid))
 }
```

(here's a [link to the referenced bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15436) and [other discussion on the devtools issue list](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/338#issuecomment-23424122)).

Looking at `/etc/passwd` on my system shows that I have userid 56347.

> bolker:x:56347:1001:Ben Bolker,,,,:/home/bolker:/bin/bash

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) says

> POSIX requires the UID to be an integer type. Most Unix-like operating systems represent the UID as an unsigned integer. The size of UID values varies amongst different systems; some UNIX OS's[which?] used 15-bit values, allowing values up to 32767, while others such as Linux supported 16-bit UIDs, making 65536 unique IDs possible. The majority of modern Unix-like systems have switched to 32-bit UIDs, allowing 4,294,967,296 (232) unique IDs.

and

> For compatibility between 16-bit and 32-bit UIDs, many Linux distributions now set it to be 2^16−2 = 65,534; the Linux kernel defaults to returning this value when a 32-bit UID does not fit into the return value of the 16-bit system calls.[11]

[Brian Ripley says](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-September/067561.html)

> A tarball can only 
>   store uids up to 'nobody' (usually 32767), and certainly larger ones 
>   cannot be unpacked portably.
>   The warnings did not occur before, but the tarball produced could cause
>   problems when unpacking with other tools.

I can't find much more documentation on this (except that Wikipedia says there are Unix systems with 15-bit uids out there). The [GNU tar page](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) appears to give `uid` as an length-8 *character* type ...

Comment: Thanks, @Ben! more helpful information than I got from Google search.

Comment: Setting `R_BUILD_TAR=tar` in your `~/.Renviron` will most likely get rid of these warnings because it will use a more modern tar tool than the one that is built into R itself.  See my full answer (below) for details.

Comment: Will CRAN allow one to "ignore" this warning?

Comment: I believe so. I've always been OK with ignoring it (and have submitted multiple packages to CRAN).

Answer (score 14):

To further clarify Ben Bolker's spot-on explanation and to provide **a workaround**, this only happens for users who have `uid` or `gid` greater than 32767, e.g.

```sh
$ id --user
60839   # <= causes the warning

$ id --group
900     # <= OK
```

This warning happens when `utils::tar()` is used *and* the internal, built-in tar function is used, which is the default.  It's in that internal function the warning is produced.  The most common reason for these warnings is when we **build** an R package, e.g. `R CMD build pkgname`.

Not easy to find, but from `help("build", package="utils")` one can read that the internal tar function can be overridden by environment variable `R_BUILD_TAR`.  So, for users on Linux and macOS, set:

```
R_BUILD_TAR=tar
```

in your `~/.Renviron`.  This will cause `R CMD build` to use `tar` on your `PATH` and most likely that tar tool will accept UIDs and GIDs larger than 32767.  This is, for instance, true for the tar tool that comes with CentOS 7:

```sh
$ tar --version | head -1
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

PS. `help("build", package="utils")` also mentions `R_INSTALL_TAR`. That seems to come in play when using `R CMD check` (sic!), so I'm not sure it's wise to set it.  For instance, you might not get warnings on too-long filenames in tarballs when you check your package locally but will fail when you submit to CRAN.

Comment: Use `R_BUILD_TAR=tar --format=gnu` to suppress "Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : using pax extended headers".